# Sorting results on a mysql table along longitude and then latitude, NOT a circular radius

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

Hey all...
I've been tasked with a global search project.
They want to search a database of pictures, all with long/lat
references storied per image in a mysql DB.

However, their search criteria is a little specific.

A simplified table structure is:
`id` INT auto inc primary
`imagePath` varchar 255
`long` DECIMAL 12,7
`lat` DECIMAL 12,7

I need to provide the SQL statement with a start long/lat position.
They then want to receive 34 images, going south from their initial
long reference.. once they get to -90 (the bottom of the earth) to pop
over 1 degree to the right/East and search up to the north to 90 and
repeat until 34 images are found.

What's confusing me is how to calculate the minus to plus changes..
ensuring that we loop up and down along the earths 'long' reference.

Has anyone done this before..?
I'd LOVE to do it in a single query...
(I've seen how one can fetch results based on a circle radius, but my client.. bless em.. doesn't want to do that)

Ok, back to google!!

Thoughts...

Tris...

Comment: Hint: convert to integers and use modular arithmetic to create a sort order multiplier, then sort first by longitude, then by latitude multiplied by the sort order multiplier. But there are a few edge cases you also need to take care of (equal latitude and potential wrap-around +180 -> -180).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs are $the_lat and $the_long

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE long > $the_long
OR ( long = $the_long AND lat >= $the_lat)
ORDER BY long ASC, lat ASC
LIMIT 34
```

As is, it's a uni-directional search -- it won't wrap around to longs < $the_long.

Comment: I'm off to google alternating sorting... or something like that!